# Automatically resize images (that have a predefined size) with browser size using CSS

Tags: html, css

In order to make images flexibles I can use the following css code:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;
}
```

Although, this doesnt let me to define a specific size for an image when the browser is on the full size.
Is there any way to do something like this :

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;
}
```

Comment: probably `max-height:150px` ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;
}

@media (min-width: 1280px) {
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
        height: auto;
        width: auto\9;
    }
}
```

By setting `min-width` and/or `max-width` you can have special rules applied only with those window sized.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve for flexible width and height can be achived using viewport height and viewport width unit of css.
Instead of using '%' or 'px' as units to your width and height, try 'vh' fir height and 'vw' for width. For an example a 50vh height is roughly 50% of browser height, so it is highly flexible with browser changes.

```
img { max-width: 100%; max-height: 150px; height: 70vh; width: 60vw; }
```

Answer (score 0):

do you already tried to use `object-fit`?

Is a good alternative to fix image sizes, just passing:

```
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```